# How to figure out z3py conditional blocks for this logic

Tags: z3py

So I have 3 houses 1,2,3 and 3 colors. When I run this script I get nicely all variations (9 in sum). 1 house with color 1, 2nd house with color 3 and so on. Now I want to add a rule, that no house is same color. So unless I know some house-color combination, I still have all 9 variations. But then I want to tell, that house 1 has color 3 and it should print(house:color) 1:3, 2:1, 2:2, 3:1, 3:2. But how would the condition look like. Maybe I need to re-arrange the code totally different?

```py
    from z3 import *
    
    color = Int('color')
    house = Int('house')
    
    color_variations = Or(color==1, color==2, color==3)
    house_variations = Or(house==1, house==2, house==3)
    
    s = Solver()
    
    s.add(color_variations)
    s.add(house_variations)
    
    myvars = [house, color]
    
    res = s.check()
    n = 1
    
    while (res == sat):
      m = s.model()
      block = []
      for var in myvars:
          v = m.evaluate(var, model_completion=True)
          print("%s = %s " % (var, v)),
          block.append(var != v)      
      s.add(Or(block))
      print("===========\n")
      res = s.check()
      n = n + 1
```

**Edit:**

I could add `s.add(And(house!=1,color!=3))` to exclude this combination, but then I don't get it as a variation in print out.

**Edit2:**

This seems to do the trick
`s.add(Or(And(house!=1,color!=3), And(house==1,color==3)))`

or

```
s.add(And(If(color==3, house==1, house_variations), If(house==1, color==3, color_variations)))
```

or

```
s.add(And(Implies(color==3, house==1), Implies(house==1,color==3)))
```

, but is some-have long'ish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be best to use an enumeration for this problem. Note that you only need to represent the colors of the houses as symbolic variables: You already know what the houses are. The trick is to require the colors to be distinct. Here's how I'd code it:

```py
from z3 import *

Color, (Red, Green, Blue) = EnumSort('Color', ('Red', 'Green', 'Blue'))

h1, h2, h3 = Consts('h1 h2 h3', Color)

s = Solver()

s.add(Distinct([h1, h2, h3]))

myvars = [h1, h2, h3]

res = s.check()

n = 1
while (res == sat):
  print("%d. " % n),
  m = s.model()
  block = []
  for var in myvars:
      v = m.evaluate(var, model_completion=True)
      print("%s = %-5s " % (var, v)),
      block.append(var != v)
  s.add(Or(block))
  print
  n = n + 1
  res = s.check()
```

When I run this, I get:

```
1.  h1 = Blue   h2 = Green  h3 = Red
2.  h1 = Green  h2 = Red    h3 = Blue
3.  h1 = Red    h2 = Blue   h3 = Green
4.  h1 = Blue   h2 = Red    h3 = Green
5.  h1 = Red    h2 = Green  h3 = Blue
6.  h1 = Green  h2 = Blue   h3 = Red
```

That is, we get all 6 possible combinations.

If you know that a given house is a particular color, just add it as an extra constraint. For instance, let's say house-2 is blue. You can add the following constraint to the above program:

```py
s.add(h2 == Blue)
```

With this addition, the output is:

```
1.  h1 = Green  h2 = Blue   h3 = Red
2.  h1 = Red    h2 = Blue   h3 = Green
```

Hope this gets you started. A good site to read through for z3py programming is: https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/guide-examples.htm

### Adding size info

If you want to add another property, just declare it like we did for `Color`:

```py
from z3 import *

Color, (Red, Green,  Blue)  = EnumSort('Color', ('Red', 'Green',  'Blue'))
Size,  (Big, Medium, Small) = EnumSort('Size',  ('Big', 'Medium', 'Small'))

h1c, h2c, h3c = Consts('h1c h2c h3c', Color)
h1s, h2s, h3s = Consts('h1s h2s h3s', Size)

s = Solver()

s.add(Distinct([h1c, h2c, h3c]))
s.add(Distinct([h1s, h2s, h3s]))

myvars = [h1c, h2c, h3c, h1s, h2s, h3s]

# Add a constrain saying house 2 is medium, and house 3 is Green
s.add(h2s == Medium)
s.add(h3c == Green)

# Rest of the program same as above, elided here for brevity
```

When I run this, I get:

```
1.  h1c = Blue   h2c = Red    h3c = Green  h1s = Big    h2s = Medium  h3s = Small
2.  h1c = Red    h2c = Blue   h3c = Green  h1s = Big    h2s = Medium  h3s = Small
3.  h1c = Red    h2c = Blue   h3c = Green  h1s = Small  h2s = Medium  h3s = Big
4.  h1c = Blue   h2c = Red    h3c = Green  h1s = Small  h2s = Medium  h3s = Big
```

Comment: than you. I'm looking into the tutorials all the time, but they are represented in away it's hard to grasp for beginners. Question what if I have more properties for they house? Like one more named Size (Small, Big, Middle). How would the code look like? Can I still use Distinct?

Comment: if you would edit ur answer and add Size, it would mean the world for me :)

Comment: It's best to ask different questions in a different thread, and show what you tried. But I edited the answer to include size info. See here for guidelines on how to ask good stack-overflow questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Best of luck!

Comment: any quick tips how to set a condition that the house why is Small is Green, not pointing to a particular house.

Comment: I don't want to open new thread right now, as again I have nothing to present what I have tried. The documentation did not give any insight to this problem.

Comment: Id did create a new thread at the end https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63423647/how-to-solve-this-exclusion-inclusion-problem-with-z3py