# How to solve this exclusion/inclusion problem with z3py?

Tags: z3py

Thanks to community help I have come up with this code:

```py
    from z3 import *
    
    Color, (Red, Green, Blue) = EnumSort('Color', ('Red', 'Green', 'Blue'))
    Size,  (Big, Medium, Small) = EnumSort('Size',  ('Big', 'Medium', 'Small'))
    
    h1c, h2c, h3c = Consts('h1c h2c h3c', Color)
    h1s, h2s, h3s = Consts('h1s h2s h3s', Size)
    
    s = Solver()
    
    myvars = [h1c, h2c, h3c, h1s, h2s, h3s]
    
    s.add(Distinct([h1c, h2c, h3c]))
    s.add(Distinct([h1s, h2s, h3s]))
    
    s.add(h3s == Medium)
    s.add(h3c == Red)
    
    res = s.check()
    
    n = 1
    while (res == sat):
      print("%d. " % n),
      m = s.model()
      block = []
      for var in myvars:
          v = m.evaluate(var, model_completion=True)
          print("%s = %-5s " % (var, v)),
          block.append(var != v)
      s.add(Or(block))
      n = n + 1
      res = s.check()
```

This solves the problem, where only one house can be, for example, Medium size and Red color. And other combinations stay as variations.

However what I also want is a condition, that the House why is, for Example, Green is Small. Not pointing initially to particular house. This would exclude all variations where Green or Small is not combined (Green can not be Medium, and Small can not be Red, etc.)... But also keep the distinct so, for example, only one house can be Green and Small. So later if I say house 1 is Green or Small, then for house 1 is this one variation and no other houses (variations) can be Green or Small.

```
Example after 1st condition (Green is Small):

h1 = Green + Small
h2 = Green + Small
h3 = Green + Small
h1 = Red + Medium
h1 = Red + Big
h2 = Red + Medium
h2 = Red + Big
h3 = Red + Medium
h3 = Red + Big
h1 = Blue + Medium
h1 = Blue + Big
h2 = Blue + Medium
h2 = Blue + Big
h3 = Blue + Medium
h3 = Blue + Big ( I might missed something)

Example after 2nd condition (House 1 is Small/Green):

h1 = Green + Small
h2 = Red + Medium
h2 = Red + Big
h3 = Red + Medium
h3 = Red + Big
h2 = Blue + Medium
h2 = Blue + Big
h3 = Blue + Medium
h3 = Blue + Big ( I might missed something)
```

I have been looking into `Functions` and `children` variable, but see no way how to compare Any variable in stack. I think the code needs to be totally reorganized?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking for. It would help to give actual examples of what you get and what you actually want to achieve. But see my answer which I hope can illuminate some of the programming tricks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JohanC's answer is just fine, but I do agree with the OP that these sorts of constraints can get really out of hand and impossible to manage if you don't approach them in a systematic way. I found that creating dictionaries and your own abstractions can really help. Note that this isn't really z3/z3py specific, but in general for programming. For instance, here's how I would code your problem:

```py
from z3 import *

Color, (Red, Green, Blue)   = EnumSort('Color', ('Red', 'Green', 'Blue'))
Size,  (Big, Medium, Small) = EnumSort('Size',  ('Big', 'Medium', 'Small'))

# Create a house and store properties in a dictionary
def mkHouse(name):
    return { 'name' : name
           , 'color': Const(name + "_color", Color)
           , 'size' : Const(name + "_size",  Size)
           }

allHouses = [mkHouse(n) for n in ["house1", "house2", "house3"]]

s = Solver ()

# Assert sizes and colors are different
s.add(Distinct([h['color'] for h in allHouses]))
s.add(Distinct([h['size']  for h in allHouses]))

def forallHouses(pred):
    cond = True
    for house in allHouses:
        cond = And(cond, pred(house))
    s.add(cond)

# Assert that Green house is small. Note the implication.
forallHouses(lambda h: Implies(h['color'] == Green, h['size'] == Small))

# Assert that If a house is Red, then it cannot be Medium
forallHouses(lambda h: Implies(h['color'] == Red, h['size'] != Medium))

# Collect the solutions:
res = s.check()

n = 1
while (res == sat):
  print("Solution %d: " % n)
  m = s.model()
  block = []
  for house in allHouses:
      hcolor = m.evaluate(house['color'], model_completion=True)
      hsize  = m.evaluate(house['size'],  model_completion=True)
      print("  %-5s = %-5s %-5s" % (house['name'], hcolor, hsize))
      block.append(Or(house['color'] != hcolor, house['size'] != hsize))
  s.add(Or(block))
  n = n + 1
  res = s.check()
```

Note the use of a dictionary to keep track of the name, size, and color of the house. You can add new properties as you wish, and everything stays local for easy manipulation and extraction later on. In particular, the function `forallHouses` captures the essence of what you're trying to say: You want to say something about each individual house, and it captures this via a lambda-function.

In the above example, I asserted the `Green` house is `Small` and `Red` house is *not* `Medium`. (This implies the `Red` house must be big, something z3 discovers for us.) When I run it, I get:

```
Solution 1:
  house1 = Blue  Medium
  house2 = Green Small
  house3 = Red   Big
Solution 2:
  house1 = Green Small
  house2 = Red   Big
  house3 = Blue  Medium
Solution 3:
  house1 = Green Small
  house2 = Blue  Medium
  house3 = Red   Big
Solution 4:
  house1 = Red   Big
  house2 = Blue  Medium
  house3 = Green Small
Solution 5:
  house1 = Red   Big
  house2 = Green Small
  house3 = Blue  Medium
Solution 6:
  house1 = Blue  Medium
  house2 = Red   Big
  house3 = Green Small
```

Which I believe is in line with what you are trying to achieve. Hopefully, you can start from this skeleton and turn it into something that you can use as you model more complicated constraints.

Answer (score 1):

One way or another you'd need to add a condition:

```
s.add(Or(And(h1c == Green, h1s == Small),
         And(h2c == Green, h2s == Small),
         And(h3c == Green, h3s == Small)))
```

Everything can be written a bit more flexible with arrays:

```py
from z3 import EnumSort, Consts, Solver, Distinct, Or, And, sat

Color, (Red, Green, Blue) = EnumSort('Color', ('Red', 'Green', 'Blue'))
Size, (Big, Medium, Small) = EnumSort('Size', ('Big', 'Medium', 'Small'))
hc = Consts('h1c h2c h3c', Color)
hs = Consts('h1s h2s h3s', Size)

s = Solver()
s.add(Distinct(hc))
s.add(Distinct(hs))

s.add(Or([And(hci == Green, hsi == Small) for hci, hsi in zip(hc, hs)]))

res = s.check()
n = 1
while (res == sat):
    print(f"{n:-2d}.", end=" ")
    m = s.model()
    block = []
    for i, (hci, hsi) in enumerate (zip(hc, hs), start=1):
        hci_v = m.evaluate(hci, model_completion=True)
        hsi_v = m.evaluate(hsi, model_completion=True)
        print(f'{f"h{i}:{hci_v}+{hsi_v}":<15}', end="")
        block.append(hci != hci_v)
        block.append(hsi != hsi_v)
    print()
    s.add(Or(block))
    n += 1
    res = s.check()
```

Result:

```
 1. h1:Blue+Big    h2:Green+Small h3:Red+Medium  
 2. h1:Green+Small h2:Red+Medium  h3:Blue+Big    
 3. h1:Red+Medium  h2:Blue+Big    h3:Green+Small 
 4. h1:Red+Big     h2:Blue+Medium h3:Green+Small 
 5. h1:Blue+Big    h2:Red+Medium  h3:Green+Small 
 6. h1:Blue+Medium h2:Red+Big     h3:Green+Small 
 7. h1:Blue+Medium h2:Green+Small h3:Red+Big     
 8. h1:Red+Big     h2:Green+Small h3:Blue+Medium 
 9. h1:Red+Medium  h2:Green+Small h3:Blue+Big    
10. h1:Green+Small h2:Blue+Medium h3:Red+Big     
11. h1:Green+Small h2:Blue+Big    h3:Red+Medium  
12. h1:Green+Small h2:Red+Big     h3:Blue+Medium
```

PS: An approach that simplifies the condition that the small house is green, is to change the representation.  Instead of representing the color and the size for each of the houses, one could represent the house number for each of the colors and each of the sizes. This will need additional conditions that each of the colors should be either 1,2 or 3. And the same condition for the sizes:

```py
from z3 import Ints, Solver, Distinct, Or, And, sat

Red, Green, Blue = Ints('Red Green Blue')
Big, Medium, Small = Ints('Big Medium Small')
colors = [Red, Green, Blue]
sizes = [Big, Medium, Small]

s = Solver()
s.add(Distinct(colors))
s.add(Distinct(sizes))
s.add(And([Or([color == i for i in (1, 2, 3)]) for color in colors]))
s.add(And([Or([size == i for i in (1, 2, 3)]) for size in sizes]))

s.add(Green == Small)

res = s.check()
n = 1
while (res == sat):
    print(f"{n:-2d}.", end=" ")
    m = s.model()
    block = []
    for x in colors + sizes:
        x_v = m.evaluate(x, model_completion=True).as_long()
        print(f"{x}:h{x_v}", end=" ")
        block.append(x != x_v)
    print()
    s.add(Or(block))
    n += 1
    res = s.check()
```

Result:

```
 1. Red:h3 Green:h2 Blue:h1 Big:h3 Medium:h1 Small:h2 
 2. Red:h2 Green:h3 Blue:h1 Big:h2 Medium:h1 Small:h3 
 3. Red:h2 Green:h3 Blue:h1 Big:h1 Medium:h2 Small:h3 
 4. Red:h1 Green:h2 Blue:h3 Big:h1 Medium:h3 Small:h2 
 5. Red:h3 Green:h2 Blue:h1 Big:h1 Medium:h3 Small:h2 
 6. Red:h1 Green:h3 Blue:h2 Big:h1 Medium:h2 Small:h3 
 7. Red:h3 Green:h1 Blue:h2 Big:h3 Medium:h2 Small:h1 
 8. Red:h3 Green:h1 Blue:h2 Big:h2 Medium:h3 Small:h1 
 9. Red:h1 Green:h3 Blue:h2 Big:h2 Medium:h1 Small:h3 
10. Red:h1 Green:h2 Blue:h3 Big:h3 Medium:h1 Small:h2 
11. Red:h2 Green:h1 Blue:h3 Big:h2 Medium:h3 Small:h1 
12. Red:h2 Green:h1 Blue:h3 Big:h3 Medium:h2 Small:h1
```

If necessary, the output could be reformatted to the same format as the first solution. Whether one solution is "less workaround" or "clearer" or "easier to maintain" seems a very subjective question. Converting a problem into a format for a SAT/SMT solver is always kind of tricky.

Comment: Yeah this works. But also feels like an workaround.

Comment: Why do you think it is a workaround? It is the normal way z3py works. See the examples at [this page](https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/guide-examples.htm) such as 8 queens and Sudoku. For many more examples, see Dennis Yurichev's  excellent [SAT/SMT by example] (https://yurichev.com/writings/SAT_SMT_by_example.pdf) or Hakan Kjellerstrand's [helper functions](http://hakank.org/z3/z3_utils_hakank.py) and [long list of examples](http://www.hakank.org/z3/).

Comment: I don't know. It just feel brute force setting thous all Green+Small combinations. I hope there is a smarter solution out there.

Comment: SAT/SMT is all about brute force. In the end everything is converted to binary expressions. If you study the examples, you'll notice that often much more involved expressions are created. For example Yurichev's solution to the [tiling puzzle (22.6 in the pdf)](https://yurichev.com/SAT_SMT_tree/other/tiling/Z3/tiling.py) has functions with double loops that are called from inside other loops, all needed to create the complex boolean expressions.

Comment: OK, thank you for you insights. If I'm not getting any other answers I accept your in few days. Thank you.

Comment: There's a million ways one can solve this problem. Johan's approach takes it from the "property" angle. I'd rather approach it from the "houses" angle, which is probably what the OP cares most about as one can add new properties at will. See my alternative solution which hopefully provides another approach by using dictionaries and lambda-functions.